# matplotlib symlog plot with non 'auto' aspect ratio

Tags: matplotlib, aspect-ratio

I am trying to change the aspect ratio of a symlog plot with matplotlib. However, it gives an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'aspect_scale_mode' referenced before assignment".

Below is the minimum modification of an official symlog plot example, found at https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/pylab_examples/symlog_demo.html

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dt = 0.01
x = np.arange(-50.0, 50.0, dt)
y = np.arange(0, 100.0, dt)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')

plt.plot(x, np.sin(x / 3.0))
plt.xscale('symlog')
plt.yscale('symlog', linthreshy=0.015)
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('symlog both')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The fact that you get an `UnboundLocalError` is a bug. One would rather expect a more useful error message here. But more generally, what is the expected outcome of an "equal aspect" in case of symlog scales? Do you have a clear concept of what the notion "aspect" would mean in such case?

Comment: I opened an issue about this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13819. Feel free to contribute with what you think the expected outcome should be.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I just wanted to customize the aspect ratio. It should not necessarily be 'equal'.

Comment: Yes, that is the question: What does the notion "aspect" mean in such case? (Say aspect=2, how would you expect the plot to look like?)

Comment: Does it especially matter for symlog? I was expecting, in the same manner as the linear axis case, to get the figure of aspect ratio 2 when I plot with a range [-1, 1]x[-2, 2].

Comment: At least to me it is not at all clear what "aspect" would mean for just any non-linear scale. For the linear scale it would mean the ratio between data units in y and data units in x direction in display space. But in the case of a log axis, this ratio is not a constant number, so I don't really know how to possibly define it. Did you read through [issue #8878](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8878)? There, people are similarly confused about a request for log aspect.

Comment: If it is semilog, I agree that it is confusing as the two axes are not on equal footing. On the other hand, if both are symlog, I think it is doable. Simply, as I said, the ratio of the length of axes is to be the ratio of range of them.

Comment: Do you mean the range in data or the range in the log of the data?

Comment: Exactly. Can you come with any possible problem with it?

Comment: The problem *is*  that I'm not sure how to define it. Range of data? Or range of log data?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant log data.